How to submit a patch to a Ubuntu bug that has been fixed upstream?
The fix for this bug is a one-liner, and it has been fixed upstream.
However, since Ubuntu 24.04 will not backport a later upstream version in its repositories, is there a way I (as a user) can submit a patch?

I already reported the bug linked in the question. My question is how I can submit a patch to the Ubuntu package
